# data Load in Jquery mobile on page id change

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create one demo application consisting of three page ids and  For every page I am using one Javascript file. For page A it is document.ready and page B and C its on PageInit event. It is working proper, but once i click back button of browser, suppose i clicked at page B and returned to page A. Now using href i  again clicked on page B link  and page B appeared. But when B  appearing, on initialisation B Javascript file should be executed but it is not happening. the data which were on Page B earler still showing not being refreshed.
Any Idea
How can I handle this...or Am i going the wrong way?

Comment: could you please post some of your code and error messages too

Comment: 1) dont use `.ready()` in jQM 2) `pageinit` fires once per page. 3) if you want to execute functions everytime page is shown use `pageshow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#' ,function()
```

instead of

```
$( document ).delegate("#", "pageinit", function()
```